# fade in fade out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to get a div to have a fade out then fade in effect, but the fade out instantly disappears then the fade in works perfectly. Its like the fade in effect interrupts the fade out immediately

js

```
$('#fillBg').stop(true,false).fadeTo(3000, 0);
$("#fillBg").hide().attr('src', bgImage).stop(false,false).fadeTo(1500, 1.0);
```

Comment: please post a jsfiddle too so we can look at the html and how the code is working

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: have you tried to put your fade in effect in the callback of your fade out effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add anything that is supposed to be happening after the first fadeTo animation into a callback function:

```
 $('#fillBg').stop(false,false).fadeTo(3000, 0, function() {
    $(this).hide().attr('src', bgImage).stop(false,false).fadeTo(1500, 1.0);
 });
```

Comment: I literally thought of this like a minute after I posted this. Thanks for the reply. Will mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the 2nd `.stop`.  Calling stop is stopping the second `fadeTo` animation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fillBg').fadeOut(3000, function(){
    $("#fillBg").attr('src', bgImage).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Will ensure the fadeIn is run after the fade Out has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
​$("#fillBg").fadeOut().fadeIn();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g334J/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback of the `fadeTo` method like this

```
//Cache the value, for performance
var divToHide = $('#fillBg');

divToHide.stop(false,false).fadeTo(3000, 0, function() {
     divToHide.hide().attr('src', bgImage).stop(false,false).fadeTo(1500, 1.0);
});
```

Or using `fadeIn`, and `fadeOut`

```
//Cache the value, for performance
var divToHide = $('#fillBg');

divToHide.fadeOut(3000, function() {
     divToHide.hide().attr('src', bgImage).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fillBg').stop(true,false).fadeTo(3000, 0, backIn);
function backIn()
{
    $("#fillBg").fadeTo(1500, 1.0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4CnjB/